# Checking 1st if condition and then 2nd

Tags: java, spring, if-statement

Is there a way to put a check in for loop where 1st loop only checks if `abb.iscurrently()` and if its true go inside the block and in 2nd loop only checks `abb.islately()` avoid checking `abb.iscurrently()`? My Current code.

```
 for (){if (abb.iscurrentlyy() || abb.islately()) {

        if (reqFiles != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < reqFiles.length; i++) {

                Future<ExecResult> lcukv = executor.submit(worker);
                executionFutureException.add(lcukv);
            }
        }

    } else { // do if condition is false.
    }
  }
```

Comment: You want to go inside the loop if both `iscurrently` and `islately` right?  Why not just do that (`abb.iscurrentlyy() && abb.islately()`)?  Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: that is my current code. i want to change this to something like in first loop i want to check only abb.iscurrentlyy() and if its true go inside the block and avoid checking abb.islately(). then in 2nd loop check abb.islately() only and ignore checking abb.iscurrenltyy().

Comment: Why not do that?  Is there another problem? `if (iscurrently()) { if (islately()) {  } }`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain the exact conditions you are looking for?

Comment: Based on what you said, a compound condition based on && would do the trick. Is the problem that you want to poll the state of `abb.iscurrentlyy()` as well as `abb.islately()` because they might be changed by some other piece of code and then act based on their states? The reason people keep asking you what you're trying to do is so we don't spend a lot of time coming up with a solution that doesn't address the underlying problem. Your code has a bit of smell to it that may suggest an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Continue;`, to skip the rest of the steps in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why someone wants to do that, But this logic should work.

```java
boolean flag = true;

for (){(flag && if (abb.iscurrentlyy()) || abb.islately()) {
    flag = false; // this will execute everytime
    if (reqFiles != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < reqFiles.length; i++) {

            Future<ExecResult> lcukv = executor.submit(worker);
            executionFutureException.add(lcukv);
        }
    }

}else{ // do if condition is false.
}}
```